# Filecopy vs name function? Differences?

Tags: vba, excel

I have found two different ways to copy single files in Excel using VBA. One is file copy:

```
FileCopy (originalPath), (pathToCopyTo)
```

The other is name:

```
Name (originalPath) As (pathToCopyTo)
```

Any differences in performance/intended use/functionality? I haven't been able to notice anything, but interested to know!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They actually do very different things.

`FileCopy` will actually make a *new copy* of the file at the location of `pathToCopyTo`, leaving the original file intact.

`Name` *renames* the original file. The effectively *moves* the file if you supply a different file path. (A copy/paste action.) So, the original file won't be where you found it, it will be in the new location.

For more information see the following MSDN documentation:

- [Name Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264639(v=office.15).aspx)
- [FileCopy Statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264390(v=office.15).aspx)

As for performance, `Name` will preform better because it's not necessary for the OS to physically copy the data on disk. It will just update the file's location in the lookup tables. Incidentally, this is also the reason Cut/Paste file operations are faster than Copy/Paste file operations.